# django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: upon running "python manage.py migrate"

Tags: python, django

I have just started a new django project, which is my own blog.
I ran this command first:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Then:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

But, upon running `python manage.py migrate`, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 86, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0012_user_following dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('account', '0002_contact')
```

I haven't even written any code yet. Then why am I getting this error?
Please help me out

Comment: did you call python manage.py makemigrations yet?

Comment: No. I have not created any models yet

Comment: If not then its probably corrupted file when installing django. Try re-installing your django since that's django's migrations file that is missing

Comment: Ok. I'll reinstall django and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

It's  probably corrupted file when installing django. Try re-installing your django since that's django's migrations file that is missing.